# Can I argue that normal form submit (POST) is slower than asynchronous POST?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, asynchronous

Since normal form submit(POST) is taking time for the page load (from the page to the server and again from the server to the page), can I argue that asynchronous call(POST) is a bit faster than that?. The assumption is I'm calling the same route and use the same internet speed.

Let's consider this is the post router.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('test.html', { root: path.dirname(require.main.filename) + '/public/' });
});
```

Comment: Who are you arguing to and for what purpose?

Comment: with myself. to understand the difference between them.